# Python name to/from file

Tags: python, file, if-statement

I want the text to display the users name if they have entered it before. I have this working in c++ but wanted to practice python. the output will continue to do the "else" statement. I have tried having the if statement search for a string such as "noname" or "empty" and it would still do the else statement.

```
fr = open('sample.txt','r')
name = fr.read()
fr.close()

if name is None:
    fw = open('sample.txt','w')
    stuff = raw_input("enter name:")
    fw.write(stuff)
    fw.close()
else:
    print(name)
```

Comment: It equals whatever is in the file. So if I wrote a name in there and the else statement ran like it should it would say "quack" if I typed quack into the txt file

Comment: I did, I get the whatever i put into the file. Such as "toby" if i put in toby or "hi" if i put in hi

Comment: do you mean if the name is already in the file?

Comment: Yes it pulls the name from the file correctly. It can print the name from the file if there is one. I'm trying to get it to say hey "name" if there is a name already in the file. I want it to prompt the user to enter a name if there is no name in the file. So pulling and putting things into and from the file works perfectly. The if statement is the problem I am having, it seems right to me but c++ is my main language so some of the logic may be weird.

Comment: so there will only potentially be one name or none?

Comment: why are you opening the file twice?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a blank file without any data in it, `f.read()` doesn't return `None`, it returns an empty string.

So rather than do `if name is None` you could write `if name == ''` or, to be certain, `if name in (None, '')`.

You might also want to make sure you add a newline character when you write the names to your file, so you should do:

```
f.write(name + '\n')
```

for example.

Edit: As Cat Plus Plus mentioned, you can just do `if name:`, because both `None` and an empty string will evaluate to `False`. I just thought it was less clear for this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

Use `with` to open files, it closes them automtically:

```
with open('sample.txt','a+') as names: # if file does not exist, "a" will create it
    lines = names.read()
    if lines: # if file has data
        print("Hello {}".format(lines))
    else: # else file is empty, ask for name and write name  to file
        name = raw_input("enter name:")
        names.write(name)
```

To check if the name exists before writing:

```
with open('sample.txt','a+') as names:
    lines = names.read()
    name = raw_input("enter name:")
    if name in lines:
        print("Hello {}".format(name))
    else:
        names.write(name)
```